# How to replace online data in web pages with offline data?

Tags: javascript, firefox, offline-caching

I run Firefox in my Windows 7 PC. There are a lot of web pages which contain inline JavaScript as well as .js lnks nowadys. Some links may be from inside, from that domain itself, while others are from outside, like `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`. is it possible to replace these links with offline data, stored in my local disk?

That is, when the browser calls for `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`, the js may load from my local disk like `c:\jquery.min.js`. Is this possible, at least with Firefox, or is there any workaround / Firefox addon or something like that?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: sometime to gain speed, but most importantly, if ajax.googleapis.com is blocked in my WiFi server (it is blocked now, and some other domans, that lnk to .js), still I can access them by this way

Comment: "sometime to gain speed" --- it's already cached by your browser. "if ajax.googleapis.com is blocked in my WiFi server" --- is it a real problem or you're trying to justify your current activity?

Comment: Alright no prob with speed. But it s blocked in my institute server. Even f I access stackoverflow, i gets a top red ribbon saying JS not loaded. Also t prevents js working in some file sharing sites like 4shared.com

Comment: is there some workaround like greasemonkey?